# Unfair coin tossed twice

Tags: probability

An unfair coin is tossed twice. The probability of heads is 3 times the probability of tails. What is the probability that at least one head is flipped?

Comment: What have you tried? In its current status, your question probably will be downvoted and closed, meaning that you won't get an answer. By providing your attempt, we can provide better help and you can learn more.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, if the probability of heads is three times the probability of tails, then we have $P(\text{heads}) = 3/4$ and $P(\text{tails}) = 1/4$.

Because the probability of getting no heads is $1/4 \cdot 1/4 = 1/16$, the probability of getting at least one head is $15/16$.

Comment: yap its right answer thnx